# Does an NPC's help action in combat help all PCs?

Tags: dnd-5e, combat

In Suits of Mist an NPC can help in combat. In particular:

> Alternatively, you can aid a friendly creature in attacking a creature within 5 feet of you. You feint, distract the target, or in some other way team up to make your ally’s attack more effective. If your ally attacks the target before your next turn, the first attack roll is made with advantage.

For an example round:

- an NPC, Aiden, helps against an enemy orc
- 3 PCs attack in order: Arthur, Barton, Charles
- orc's action
- back to Aiden

Do all three PCs have advantage? Or does Aiden chose one of the PCs to help?

What if the orc attacks between Aiden's help and Arthur's attack?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

### Help only provides advantage for a single ally and only for a single attack

Everything in the text of Help uses the singular for who you're helping

- "...a friendly creature..."
- "...ally's..."
- "...your ally"

So it only provides advantage for a single ally. Also note the last sentence which further limits Help to only providing advantage for the first attack roll made by that ally before the next turn.